# Remove duplicate words using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove repetitive words in string so that `'the (the)'` will become `'the'`. Why can't I do it as follows?

```
re.sub('(.+) \(\1\)', '\1', 'the (the)')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to doubly escape the back-reference:

```
re.sub('(.+) \(\\1\)', '\\1', 'the (the)')
--> the
```

Or use the [`r` prefix](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html):

> When an "r" or "R" prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string.

```
re.sub(r'(.+) \(\1\)', r'\1', 'the (the)')
--> the
```

Comment: @eumiro Yup, I just had to find a link to the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html): 'Raw string notation (r"text") keeps regular expressions sane.'